# How do I fix "petalinux-build --sdk" errors?

Tags: xilinx

I am really new in Ubuntu, I want to implement Zynq Ultrascale MPSoc VCU TRD 2018.1 Design Module-2 application on Zcu106 Board. However, after I ran the `petalinux-build --sdk` step, I got some errors. I searched and found solutions in many websites and I applied them but they didn't work. Here is an error:

```
Error Summary
-------------

ERROR: petalinux-user-image-1.0-r0 do_populate_sdk: Function failed: do_populate_sdk
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/yonetici/TRD_HOME/apu/vcu_petalinux_bsp/xilinx-sdirx-vcu-sditx-trd-zcu106-zu7-v2018.1-final/build/tmp/work/plnx_zynqmp-xilinx-linux/petalinux-user-image/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_populate_sdk.26283
ERROR: Task (/home/yonetici/TRD_HOME/apu/vcu_petalinux_bsp/xilinx-sdirx-vcu-sditx-trd-zcu106-zu7-v2018.1-final/project-spec/meta-plnx-generated/recipes-core/images/petalinux-user-image.bb:do_populate_sdk) failed with exit code '1'
```

Then I applied these steps :

```
$ mkdir -p <plnx-proj-root>/project-spec/meta-user/recipes-qt/qt5/    

$ vim <plnx-proj-root>/project-spec/meta-user/recipes-qt/qt5/nativesdk-qtbase_%.bbappend    

nativesdk-qtbase_%.bbappend content

do_generate_qt_environment_file[umask] = "022"
```

These worked fine (I checked the file) but I still got the same errors.

Then I tried increase the time out in XSCT like in this link:

- https://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/69812.html

That also didn't work. Finally, I changed timeout value 180 to 1800 but it didn't make any difference.

I use PetaLinux 2018.1. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem? If not, can you share the relevant error message from the log file, i.e. `/home/yonetici/TRD_HOME/apu/vcu_petalinux_bsp/xilinx-sdirx-vcu-sditx-trd-zcu106-zu7-v2018.1-final/build/tmp/work/plnx_zynqmp-xilinx-linux/petalinux-user-image/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_populate_sdk.26283` ?